# Cannot use gatling conf values in scala class.

Tags: scala, ssl, config, gatling

I have a gatling project where I set up cert locations using gatling.conf for 2-way ssl connection. I need to use these certificates in a helper function in the same project. I am unable to specify conf variables gatling.http.ssl.trustStore.file and gatling.http.ssl.keyStore.file in my scala class as it errors with the following error. Note that I can use application.conf variables in my code with out any issues

Code that errors:

```
   val trustStoreLoc = config.getString("gatling.http.ssl.trustStore.file")
```

Error is:

```
[error] Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'gatling'
[error]         at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKey(SimpleConfig.java:124)
[error]         at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:147)
[error]         at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:159)
[error]         at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:164)
[error]         at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getString(SimpleConfig.java:206)
[error]         at oncue.gatling.authbe.benchmarks.auth.userOpsSimulation.<init>(userOpsSimulation.scala:21)
[error]         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[error]         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
[error]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[error]         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
[error]         at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
[error]         at io.gatling.core.runner.Runner.run(Runner.scala:37)
[error]         at io.gatling.app.Gatling.start(Gatling.scala:235)
[error]         at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromMap(Gatling.scala:54)
[error]         at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.runGatling(Gatling.scala:79)
[error]         at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.runGatling(Gatling.scala:58)
[error]         at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:50)
[error]         at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gatling uses Typesafe Config's `withFallback` mechanism to allow to have :

- system properties overriding...
- ...`gatling.conf` values overriding...
- ... `gatling-defaults.conf` values

This mechanism is implemented here : https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/master/gatling-core/src/main/scala/io/gatling/core/config/GatlingConfiguration.scala#L73-77

My guess is that you only use `gatling.conf` and in this case, if the line is commented, the value is simply not defined.

Either uncomment that property in your `gatling.conf` or reuse GatlingConfiguration logic to take `gatling.conf` values into account.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Pierre. You are correct. I had to reuse the logic using Typesafe Config and I was able to use both gatling and application conf variables in my code. Code that worked:  `val gatlingConfFile = ConfigFactory.load("gatling")
  val trustStoreLoc = gatlingConfFile.getString(<PATH-TO-FILE>)`